# Is it possible to output a string containing elements (condensing non-consecutive duplicates) of an array in O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, string, lua, time-complexity

Question: Given an array that may contain non-consecutive duplicate elements, how could you output a string to display quantities in the order they appeared?

Here's a little exposition, skip below for my question. I was posed a problem to output duplicate, consecutive strings ordered in an array such that given an array, a new string would be outputted in quantities.

Given:

```
local Items = {"Wood", "Wood", "Wood", "Rope", "Rope"}
```

The output would be:

```
3x Wood 2x Rope
```

My approach was to iterate through the array and check the subsequent element for equality. I would then increment a counter and add it to a string.

```
local unpackedItems = ""
local index = 1
while index <= #Items do
    local count = 1
    while Items[index] == Items[index + 1] do 
        count = count + 1
        index = index + 1 
    end
    unpackedItems = unpackedItems .. count .. "x " .. Items[index] .. " "
    index = index + 1
end
print(unpackedItems)
```

This worked fine, though I'm curious if it could be better.

---

My question again is what about non-consecutive duplicates? Given an array that may contain duplicate elements, how could you output a string to display quantities in the order they appeared?

Given:

```
local Items = {"Wood", "Wood", "Wood", "Rope", "Rope", "Wood"}
```

Output:

```
4x Wood 2x Rope
```

My solution here was to iterate through the array and check the other elements, and to store checked indices in a hash table.

```
local unpackedItems = ""
local checked = {}
local index = 1
while index <= #Items do
    if not checked[index] then
        local count = 1
        local currentItem = Items[index]
        for index2 = index + 1, #Items do
            if not checked[index2] and currentItem == Items[index2] then
                checked[index2] = true
                count = count + 1
            end
        end
        unpackedItems = unpackedItems .. count .. "x " .. Items[index] .. " "
    end
    index = index + 1 
end
print(unpackedItems)
```

Is there a better way to accomplish this, perhaps with a time complexity of O(n)? Not too hung up on space complexity.

Also, I'm concatenating the string each time, wouldn't this be costly, especially for larger strings?

The reason I didn't use a hash table to represent the data or to convert towards was that it would lose the original order it appeared in. Another solution I considered was to convert the table into a string and manipulating it like that, but that wouldn't treat each element as its own entity. I want to prevent name "clashes", as "Wood" and "Fire Wood" may not be treated separately.

The language used was Lua, but I'm also curious to see solutions in any language.

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) `My question is, what about non-consecutive duplicates?` appears pretty far down your post: do your best not to set readers down an unwanted path. (The title might be a good place. Did you digest [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) Hash table implementations are expected to take constant "expected" time per member query/update.

Comment: @greybeard You're definitely right. That was my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below counts non-consecutive duplicates:

```
local Items = {"Wood", "Wood", "Wood", "Rope", "Rope", "Wood"}
local Count = {}
local n = 0

for i,v in ipairs(Items) do
    if Count[v]==nil then
        n=n+1
        Count[n]=v
        Count[v]=0
    end
    Count[v]=Count[v]+1
end

for k,v in ipairs(Count) do
    print(k,v,Count[v])
end
```

This a typical Lua solution: it exploits Lua tables to update counts in constant time.

The code uses `Count` for two purposes: counting duplicates and recording the order the values appear.

Comment: From OP: "*how could you output a string to display quantities in the order they appeared?*"  Wouldn't this output have no particular sort order?  `pairs()` doesn't return things in original key creation order, does it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I stated the reason I didn't want to use the hash part like this was because it wouldn't preserve the order. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: If not, maybe iterate through items again at the end, and (pseudocode) if Count[v] then print item and Count[v]; delete Count[v]; next?

Comment: In Java, there is [LinkedHashMap<K,V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) with *insertion-order* as the default *iteration order*.

Comment: @lhf Ah, interesting solution. You stored the count in the hash map portion and the order in the array part? To be clear, since you're iterating again in count, would this be O(2n) -> O(n)?

Comment: @Charlie Yes, as strings can't collide with numbers, the same table is used for both purposes. And big-O-Notation eats constants – even iterating a million times (as long as that million doesn't depend on the number of things) would still be O(n). Here, you're doing `n+m` steps (where `n` is the length of the initial list and `m` is the number of unique items). Set `m=c*n` where `0<=c<=1` (filtering unique items can't add more), so you're doing `n+m = n+c*n = (1+c)*n` steps, which means it's best (lower bound `c=1`) / worst (upper bound `c=2`) / any (`c` in between) case O(n).